# The derivative matrix in the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis

So, I have to analyze the solution $(0,0,0,0)$ of the system of equations using Implicit Function theorem:
$$\begin {cases} 
(uv)^4+(u+s)^3+t=0 \\ \sin(uv)+e^{v+t^2}-1=0
\end {cases}, (u,v,s,t)\in \mathbb R^4 $$.

**My attempt:** Let $\vec{F}=(F_1,F_2)=((uv)^4+(u+s)^3+t,sin(uv)+e^{v+t^2}-1)$. So far I have
$$D \vec{F}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial t}\\\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 4u^3v^4+3(u+s)^2 & 4u^4v^3 & 3(u+s)^2 & 1\\vcos(uv) & ucos(uv)+e^{v+t^2} & 0 & 2te^{v+t^2}\end{bmatrix}$$
At the solution $(0,0,0,0)$
$$D\vec{F}(0,0,0,0)=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & 0& 0& 1\\0 & 0& 0& 0 \end {bmatrix}$$

Does this imply that none of the variables can be locally functions of other variables?

Comment: why does $u\cos(uv)+e^{v+t^2}$ give 0 and not 1 ??

Comment: ohh, thanks, problem solved

Comment: Maybe you could answer your own question. It could help someone in the future, don’t you think ?